# Deleted Profile Pictures in Gmail

Tags: gmail, account-management, profile-picture

Up until yesterday, those who had a Gmail profile picture would appear when I received an email from them. Now, no sender's profile picture appears and instead the first letter of their name has replaced their picture. Why can I not see the sender's profile picture anymore? I have not changed anything. Is this change made automatically from Google/Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes. The change was made out of your influence reach. This is due to the fact that Google+ got discontinued and therefore all pictures were deleted. This can be resolved if the sender will upload his profile picture in his Gmail settings:

[image: 0]

or on top right:

[image: 0]